# Is there a source connecting the spices of the temple incense to the various sefirot?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Does anyone know of a source or passage in Kabbalah or Hasidic literature that links the various spices for the Temple incense to the sefirot?

Comment: Kabbalistic thinking is pretty insistent that there are only 10 sefirot, not 11 https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yetzirah.1.4?lang=he

Answer (score 5):

Remak in [Tefillah LeMoshe](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21851&st=&pgnum=118) notes the correspondences between the 11 spices of the *ketoret* and the 10 *sefirot* plus the Heavenly Throne as follows:

1. *Tzori* - *Tiferet*
2. *Tziporen* - *Hesed*
3. *Helbanah* - *Gevurah*
4. *Levonah* - *Keter*
5. *Mor* - *Malkhut*
6. *Ketziah* - *Netzah*
7. *Shibolet nerd* - *Hod*
8. *Karkom* - *Yesod*
9. *Kosht* - *Binah*
10. *Kilufah* - *Kisei*
11. *Kinammon* - *Hokhmah*